# pick Random entry from external array node

Tags: arrays, node.js

So im trying to automaically retrieve a random entry from an array listed in a seperate node.js file

function code

```
var replies = require('./replies');
function followed(event) {
  var name = event.source.name;
  var flname = event.source.screen_name;
  var myArray = [replies]; 
  var item = myArray[(Math.random()*myArray.length)|0];
  var followtweet = '@' + flname + item;
  if(flname != "UserName") {
  tweetIt(followtweet);
  console.log('\n@' + flname + ' Followed You');
  console.log('\nYou Tweeted:\n ' + followtweet);
} else {
  console.log(' Interferance From Another Bot! \n');
}

}
```

External Array

```
module.exports = {
    followedone:         'one',
    followedtwo:         'two',
    followedthre:         'three',
    replyone:         ' one',
    replytwo:         ' two',
    replythre:         ' three',
```

}

When I Run This and the function runs i get this

```
@LandscapesLucid Followed You

You Tweeted:
 @LandscapesLucid[object Object]

Waiting For The Next Action
```

I'm not sure why its only showing the [object Object] instead of either one two or three like in the array

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change from this

```
var item = myArray[(Math.random()*myArray.length)|0];
```

to this?

```
var item = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
```